# How can ı refresh the view controller after inApp payment?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to refresh my view controller after inApp payment.

I have purchase modal when I open this modal and purchasing a product, my app doesn't pass premium account but only when ı restart my app then its pass premium account.

I need to refresh my app after purchasing automatically...

I tried many things but ı cant solves the problem.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I tried these ways.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please take the [tour] and review [ask]. *"... when ı restart my app ..."* Presumably, whatever you're doing there needs to also be done after confirming the purchase, but we have no idea what you're doing without more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach here is to make views watching over premium status and updating their content whenever it changes.

You can use several methods here to communicate with your code that handles premium change:

For example you can use `NSNotificationCenter` - each view listens to "PremiumChange" event and inside your code that handles the status change you trigger it.
You can also simply observe the premium status of a user via `Combine` or `ReactiveKit`.

I strongly advice to not do it based on ViewController transitions only.
From my experience the best way is to be ready to handle premium status at any time - everywhere it is needed independly from which view is currently displayed it's best if all of them are prepared to reload. There are several scenarios like "Restoring purchases" or simply loading receipts that can be delayed. It is also safer for handling any future purchase points to avoid bugs related to this.

Also it is always a good idea to have some kind of DebugMenu inside application to let QA turn it on / off whenever they want without doing real purchases.